# How to select all values and hide NULL values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

so in my database some rows have NULL values, and when I select * from table, that NULL values also shows as text "null". So I want to hide all NULL values. Does anyone have idea for query? Thanks!

this is my input in DB:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (name VARCHAR, kg VARCHAR,   pod                 VARCHAR,reps VARCHAR, time VARCHAR );");
  db.execSQL("INSERT INTO table VALUES('name 1',NULL,NULL , NULL , '"+s+"');");
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO table VALUES(NULL,'S 1','"+ee5+"' , '"+ee+"' , '"+s+"');");
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO table VALUES(NULL,'S 2','"+ee6+"' , '"+ee2+"', '"+s+"');");
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO table VALUES(NULL,'S 3','"+ee7+"' , '"+ee3+"', '"+s+"');");
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO table VALUES(NULL,'S 4','"+ee8+"' , '"+ee4+"', '"+s+"');");
```

Comment: to hide the text "null" and display empty data, you have to go settings/preferences of your client

Comment: @DheereshSingh but if I do that then all column where I have NULL values is not showing, I only want hide that fields with NULL values

Comment: @deathApril I work in eclipse..where are settings/preferences?

Comment: eclipse is not an SQL client, do you mean Eclipse SQL Explorer? i don't have it, but look for an option under Window > SQL Explorer > SQL Editor,, or when you right click on the null value - if there is no option to change the display of <null> values, use one of the `case` / `ifnull` / `nvl` / `coalesce` answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT x, y, etc, CASE WHEN field IS NOT NULL THEN field ELSE '' END AS hehe FROM table;
```

**Edit**: Addin to your comments, this is pretty trivial once you know how to do it for one column. Apply the same for all columns. In SO dont expect homeworks to get done, instead expect a help to solve your problem which ultimately you yourself have to do.

Btw, here is how..

```
SELECT COALESCE(name, ''), COALESCE(kg, ''), COALESCE(pod, ''), COALESCE(reps, ''), 
       COALESCE(time, '') 
FROM   table
```

You have three good methods in this thread (including mine), and I personally feel the other two are more intuitive. Use any by applying the same logic as I have shown.

Comment: I edited post and this is my code, with what do I need to replace "field" depending on my code

Comment: @user1414682 so which field do you want to hide? NULL values from all fields?

Comment: I do not know what is catch with cursor. Do a search for it in android circles, or google it. Should be something trivial.

Comment: thank you very much, you've all been very helpful, I also have cursor in my code so I had to add aliases in query so that cursor can discern fields

Comment: mm good to know @user1414682, for more troubles on that in any case, you have to make it a separate question since what u have asked here for has been well answered. Now time to accept your preferred answer! :)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the data type of the column.

```
-- If the data type is integer:
SELECT COALESCE(the_column, 0)
FROM the_table;

-- or, if the column is a char or varchar type:
SELECT  COALESCE(the_column, 'some text here')
FROM the_table;

-- or, if it is a date:
SELECT  COALESCE(the_column, '1900-01-01')
FROM the_table;
```

BTW: some databases have the IFNULL() function which does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

in SQLite you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., ifnull(coln, '') FROM TABLE
```

Comment: taken from [this source](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull); I don't know much about SQLite

Comment: nawfal's solution also works, and it is DBMS-independent, being pure SQL.

Comment: use standard `coalesce` instead of `ifnull` (syntax is the same, but more than 2 columns possible)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT* FROM TableName
WHERE ValueCol IS NOT NULL
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

if you're working with sqlite for android

look at this [Article](http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html)

Comment: @Mido but if I do that then all column where I have NULL values is not showing, I only want hide that fields with NULL values