# MYSQL Query for getting non null coloumn names

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the coloumns names which are not null based up on name which I have given.

My DB looks like this

```
name user p1 p2 p3 p4 
test ravi 21 22 
test jan 56 75 
ravi test       56 75 
ravi test       75 34
```

So when I select name as ravi it should give me the output of the coloumns names p1,p2 (should not display the null coloumns) and if I give ravi it should display p1,p2 coloumns names not the values.

here I have tried my Query.

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='details' 
AND column_name LIKE 'Q%' 
AND is_nullable = 'NO' 
AND 'user'='test';
```

So can any one help me how to solve this

Comment: You can use `COALESCE` function in your `SELECT` clause
You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11169129/2763765

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the list of non-NULL column names.  You can do this with `concat()`:

```
select `user`,
       ws_concat(',',
                 (case when p1 is not null then 'p1' else '' end),
                 (case when p2 is not null then 'p2' else '' end),
                 (case when p3 is not null then 'p3' else '' end),
                 (case when p4 is not null then 'p4' else '' end)
                ) as NonNullColumns
from t
where `user` = 'ravi';
```

A SQL statement has to have well-defined columns.  So, you cannot put each column name in a separate columns -- then you would need a variable number of columns in the result set (*not* allowed).

Comment: Perfect it worked for me thanks. But I was displaying me multiple times How can I limit to one time. I am getting out put Like Ravi p1 p1...; ravi p1, p2.. But I want only one time like ravi P1, P2. thats it.

Comment: @user2787300 . . . Your sample data only has one row where `user = 'ravi'`, so it shouldn't get multiple rows.  For cases where there are multiple rows, you would need to specify what you want.