# Display images in mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

here are my table structure and row with value

```
+------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+-------+
|pfno | year  | pic1  | pic2   |  pic3 |   pic4 |   pic5 |   pic6|
+------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+-------+
|012345|2009_10|1.jpg  |2.jpg   |NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL  |
+------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+-------+
|012345|2010_11|1.jpg  |2.jpg   |NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL  |
+------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+-------+
|012345|2011_12|1.jpg  |2.jpg   |3.jpg   |4.jpg  |5.jpg   | NULL  |
```

I want to display images which value (like 1.jpg) on the database, do not show the images whose value is NULL in the database.

What i have tried is:

```
$sql_placedetail="SELECT * FROM scanned_apr where pfno='5306814' and year=2009-10 "; 
$sql_row_placedetail=mysql_query($sql_placedetail); 
while($sql_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_row_placedetail)) {
<img src='../apr/".$sql_res['year']."/".$sql_res['pfno']."/".$sql_res['pic1'] ." ' >
}
```

If you show the above table structure year 2009_10 has only 2 images but in year 2010_11 has 5 images, I want to display year wise Images as user select

Please help me out

Comment: show some code here whatever you try for this

Comment: Does your table really only have a single row?

Comment: Means your query should return those columns of `pic` that has value and are not null?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168914/how-to-select-all-values-and-hide-null-values-in-sql

Comment: $sql_placedetail="SELECT * FROM scanned_apr where pfno='5306814' and year=2009-10 ";
     $sql_row_placedetail=mysql_query($sql_placedetail);
     while($sql_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_row_placedetail))
     {<img src='../apr/".$sql_res['year']."/".$sql_res['pfno']."/".$sql_res['pic1'] ." ' >

Comment: no error but img symbol on screen

Comment: 1) why don't you put img tag in echo part? 2) Try reading the source code of broken image you are getting

Comment: +------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+-------+
|pfno | year  | pic1  | pic2   |  pic3 |   pic4 |   pic5 |   pic6|
+------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+-------+
|012345|2009_10|1.jpg  |2.jpg   |NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL  |
+------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+-------+

Answer (score 0):

How about this:-

```
$sql_placedetail="SELECT * FROM scanned_apr where pfno='5306814' and year=2009-10"; 
$sql_row_placedetail=mysql_query($sql_placedetail); 
while($sql_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_row_placedetail)){

    foreach($sql_res as $val){
        $src=null;
        if(trim($val)!=""){
            $src='../apr/'.$sql_res['year'].'/'.$sql_res['pfno'].'/'.$sql_res['pic1'];
            echo '<img src="'.$src.'" >';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try like this code

```
$sql_placedetail="SELECT * FROM scanned_apr where pfno='5306814' and year=2009-10 "; 
$sql_row_placedetail=mysql_query($sql_placedetail); 
$sql_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_row_placedetail); 
if($sql_res['pic1']!="" && $sql_res['pic1']!=NULL)
{
$img="<img src='../apr/$sql_res['year']/$sql_res['pfno']/$sql_res['pic1']' ><br/>";
}
if($sql_res['pic2']!="" && $sql_res['pic2']!=NULL)
{
$img="<img src='../apr/$sql_res['year']/$sql_res['pfno']/$sql_res['pic2']' ><br/>";
}
if($sql_res['pic3']!="" && $sql_res['pic3']!=NULL)
{
$img="<img src='../apr/$sql_res['year']/$sql_res['pfno']/$sql_res['pic3']' ><br/>";
}
if($sql_res['pic4']!="" && $sql_res['pic4']!=NULL)
{
$img="<img src='../apr/$sql_res['year']/$sql_res['pfno']/$sql_res['pic4']' ><br/>";
}
if($sql_res['pic5']!="" && $sql_res['pic5']!=NULL)
{
$img="<img src='../apr/$sql_res['year']/$sql_res['pfno']/$sql_res['pic5']' ><br/>";
}
if($sql_res['pic6']!="" && $sql_res['pic6']!=NULL)
{
echo $img="<img src='../apr/$sql_res['year']/$sql_res['pfno']/$sql_res['pic6']' ><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vadival I got the answer