# SELECT finds result for non-existent id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

In my database I collect songs that were requested during a steam. Each song is requested by a known user. I want to implement the functionality that each user can rate a requested song. Given that situation you may take a look at my database model:

[image: Database model]

Now I want to select a specifiy song_request identified by its id along with the average rating for this song as well as how often the song got rated. For this I want to use the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    sr.id, 
    sr.user_id, 
    sr.title, 
    sr.link, 
    sr.request_time, 
    COALESCE(AVG(r.rating), 0) AS rating,  
    COUNT(r.sr_id) AS votes
FROM song_requests sr LEFT OUTER JOIN sr_ratings r
    ON sr.id = r.sr_id
WHERE sr.id = 12345;
```

In my song_requests table I have the following data:

[image: song_request row]

And in the sr_ratings table some example ratings:

[image: sr_ratings example]

If I execute the SQL with

```
sr.id = 1
```

in the WHERE clause I get the following expected result:

[image: query_ok_result]

If I now use the id of a song_request that doesn't exist

```
sr.id = 12345
```

I will get the following result:

[image: query_bad_result]

I am expecting the query to not find any result because the id doesn't exist. Where am I going wrong here ? And what do I need to do to get the desired result ?

Comment: The problem is the left join

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using (and no others).  (2) Just switch to an inner join.

Comment: Inner join return exactly the same result

Comment: Thanks for the hints about the images and missing tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.  First, you are clearly using MySQL, because the code would be bogus in almost any other database.  You have an aggregation function, along with non-aggregated columns and no `GROUP BY` clause.

I am guessing you want something like this:

```
SELECT sr.id, sr.user_id, sr.title, sr.link, sr.request_time, 
       COALESCE(AVG(r.rating), 0) AS rating,  
       COUNT(r.sr_id) AS votes
FROM song_requests sr LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     sr_ratings r
     ON sr.id = r.sr_id
WHERE sr.id = 12345
GROUP BY sr.id, sr.user_id, sr.title, sr.link, sr.request_time;
```

Voila!  You'll discover that this fixes your problem.  This will return no rows.

Your code returns one row because it is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`.  That always returns exactly one row, even if there are no matches.  It turns out that the problem isn't the `LEFT JOIN`; it is the bad use of `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That indeed fixed it, thank you very much. Just to get it clear: Using an aggregation function like AVG or COUNT means I must use a group by ?

Comment: @IonicBlaze . . . Normally you would use `GROUP BY`, otherwise you will always get one row.

Answer (score 0):

The `LEFT JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` keyword returns all records from the left table, and the matched records from the right table. The result is `NULL` from the right side, if there is no match.

You can try the `IS NOT NULL` on the `CASE` statement. There is also another question that could answer yours. [How to select all values and hide NULL values in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168914/how-to-select-all-values-and-hide-null-values-in-sql)